# many-body problems and why they are so hard

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, quantum-chemistry

I am currently reading my first course in electronic structure theory and i have questions relating to the complexity of the many-body Schrödinger equation for quantum chemistry. More precisely about why we don't solve the eigenvalue problem $H\Psi = E\Psi$.

For most purposes we might just use an iterative scheme like [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration) to obtain the lowest eigenvalues, we need in total $3N$

But this seems intractable. I understand that the number of matrix elements grow fast, but surely, with the current CPU power we should be able to solve this problem right? How come we need to turn to methods like [Hartree-Fock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) and [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory)?

Comment: I'd suggest you edit to provide links to key question topics, like Arnoldi Iteration, which would not be familiar to most users.

Comment: I think you should carefully consider how large the matrix $H$ is if you have $N$ sites and $N$ particles, all interacting. You should find your matrix $H$ grows exponentially large in $N$.

Comment: Exponential growth is a pain. Moore's law tells us that every few years, we can solve a problem for one extra degree of freedom. Yey.

Comment: Along the same lines, a system of $N$ quantum particles has a lot more than $3N$ degrees of freedom (even a classical system will have $6N$ in most cases, including the momentum coordinates).